# Android How to check .apk are using Multidex?

Tags: android, apk, android-multidex

I got an "old" .apk build from colleague, and I wanted to check whether it support [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.html) or not. But I don't have the old projects files, is it possible to check it only from the .apk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename this "old.apk" to "old.zip", and unzip it, if there is only one "classes.dex", it doesn't support multidex, and if there are "classes.dex"、"classes2.dex"...it support multidex

Comment: What if the .apk actually support Multidex but it only has one classes.dex, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio,

1. Build >> Analyze APK

that will display dex files.